# NestJs proxy middleware with database access

Tags: typescript, proxy, nestjs, typeorm

I have an proxy middleware configured with nestjs and now I want to have database access within the `onProxyReq` function but I don't know if that is even possible from here. I also want to have access to the user that is currently logged in. For `controller` functions I have the `@User()` parameter decorator to get the user but how would I get that here?
This is how I implement the proxy:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

[...]

 app.use(
    '/api/proxyServer',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://someHost.com:3000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/proxyServer': '',
      },
      onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
        // I want to have access to the user here and also to the database
        proxyReq.removeHeader('Authorization');
        proxyReq.setHeader(
          'Authorization',
          'Bearer XXXX....',
        );
      },
    }),
  );
```